# When booking a bus transfer with Ryanair, how does one retrieve the actual bus ticket?

Tags: airport-transfer, london, ryanair, stn

I've booked an airport transfer in London along with my flight ticket. However I'm now confused about how do I go about getting the actual **bus ticket**. Is it sufficient to show my boarding pass? Would I get an extra email later on? Would I get the ticket while checking-in?

It's really confusing.

Comment: I'm guessing it'll be a National Express coach. Hence you might receive a confirmation from them.

Comment: NatEx sounds far too pricey for Ryanair. Seems more likely they'd charter something clapped out and rusting.

Comment: @JoErNanO yes, National Coach. But knowing Ryanair I won't be surprised I was supposed to do an 'online check-in' for the bus or pay a 100-pound fee :)

Comment: You pay the fee when you buy the ticket and it is often as much per singly bus travel as you pay for the flight, (if you are good at getting cheap flights).

Comment: @willeke sad truth :(

Comment: Yes, thank you!
I was getting stressed out about this just now.
TG for Google and your post! 

Answer (score 17, accepted):

OK, here's the answer. Three hours after making my booking I've received the following email from National Express:

[image: ryanair transfer stansted ticket]

So the answer is to wait a few hours while they issue a ticket.

Comment: totally confusing from them, thanks for posting the answer to your own question the day after

Comment: This is how it should work, however a friend of mine never received the email from National Express (Stansted to Liverpool Street). When they arrived at Stansted, they went to the National Express office inside the airport, where the clerk told them that sometimes, due to unknown reasons, the email never arrives. The clerk then proceeded to print out the ticket after seeing the Ryanair payment receipt.

Answer (score 4):

National Express Terms and Conditions for Ticket Sales online through
Ryanair.com - https://www.ryanair.com/doc/apt/transfer/LGW.pdf

> Receiving your Ticket: Please note, after having made a booking in-path through Ryanair.com, you will receive a ticket via email within 24 hours