# When booking a bus transfer with Wizz Air, how does one retrieve the actual bus ticket?

Tags: tickets, airport-transfer, buses, wizz-air, ltn

I've booked an airport transfer from London Victoria to Luton Airport along with my Wizz Air ticket. However I'm now confused about how do I go about getting the actual **bus ticket**.

Is it sufficient to show my boarding pass?

Would I get an extra email later on?

Would I get the ticket while checking-in?

Comment: Related: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/62676/when-booking-a-bus-transfer-with-ryanair-how-does-one-retrieve-the-actual-bus-t

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It turns out one can view their bus ticket on [P-Airbus.com](https://www.p-airbus.com/index.php?page=mybooking):

[image]

Enter the flight confirmation number along with the email used on Wizzair.com to reveal the E-ticket:

[image]

I think they're supposed to send out a notification 3 days before the flight takes place, but there's no need to wait for it. If the ticket doesn't show up on P-Airbus.com, it's possible to receive it by contacting the transfer service support at **wizzair@wizztransfer.com**.